# Evaluating a string as Regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to evaluate user input from a form field as a Regex expression to match against a URL using PHP's [preg_match()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function.

The user would be expected to enter a Regex expression like `^\/test\/(.*)\/?$`

This input would be passed as a string literal to `preg_match` as follows:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // /test/onetwothree/, for example
$regex = $_POST['regex__user_input']; // ^\/test\/(.*)\/?$
$match = preg_match($regex, $url);
```

This regex should match the pattern but `preg_match` is not returning a result.

I think I need to add some delimiters or maybe use [preg_quote()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php)? I tried some variations but no dice.

Answer (score 1):

you lost `/` at the begin and end of your regex.you can fill it in code or let user fill it.
`preg_match` return match return in reference parameters.as my code below

```php
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // /test/onetwothree/, for example
$regex = $_POST['regex__user_input']; // ^\/test\/(.*)\/?$
$regex = '/'.$regex.'/'; // you lost this
preg_match($regex, $url ,$matches); 
print_r($matches)
```